# Unable to get embedded device to ping anything on the network

Tags: networking, ip, embedded, busybox, buildroot

I have an embedded device, built using buildroot, kernel version 3.6.11 running busybox. The kernel is built with completely default options. I have configured the device according to what the network guy has specified for the IP, gateway, netmask etc and I have put these values in the /etc/network/interfaces file. When the system boots up, a call to `ifconfig` tells me that all the network settings are what they are supposed to be. However, I cannot ping any other machine on the same subnet as the device. I can communicate with my host machine with a direct ethernet cable connection so I think the network adapter is ok - I can `ssh` to the host, and the host can view the target correctly from the `vsftpd` I have installed on the device. 
Basically I am very unsure how to proceed with diagnosing the problem. I am drowning on internet forum linux network setup guides and getting nowhere. Also, worryingly, when I type

```
# ip addr show dev eth0
```

I get the report of a segfault in libuClibc-0.9.33.2.so. I built this all using buildroot and it reported that everything was successful. Is it possible that I have a broken kernel?? I really do not know how to proceed so any advice would be gratefully received.

**EDIT** The output from `ip addr show dev eth0` is

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen
    1000 link/ether 00:18:7d:19:a0:d8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.255.212/24 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global eth0
[  331.700545] ip[951]: segfault at 0 ip b76e1f26 sp bfbd29b0 error 4 in 
libuClibc-0.9.33.2.so[b76b5000+4d000]
Segmentation fault
```

When I call the same command on the other adapter eth1, then I get no segfault, so really don't know what is going on.

**EDIT2** After rebuilding with debug information and `strace` I was able to get strace output of the segfault - I do not really know what this means though other than it looks like it is trying to write to a location it perhaps should not (I have not included it all, just the last few lines).

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
ioctl(4, SIOCGIFTXQLEN, {ifr_name="eth1", ifr_qlen=1000}) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
write(1, "3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP"..., 793: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
) = 79
write(1, "    link/ether 00:18:7d:19:a0:d7"..., 55    link/ether 00:18:7d:19:a0:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
) = 55
open("/etc/iproute2/rt_scopes", O_RDONLY) = 4
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, 0xbfc91b30) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
read(4, "#\n# reserved values\n#\n0\tglobal\n2"..., 4096) = 92
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
write(1, "    inet 192.168.12.198/16 brd 1"..., 65    inet 192.168.12.198/16 brd 192.168.255.255 scope global eth1
) = 65
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: If it segfaults in the library, it might be a broken library, a badly built `iproute` package (perhaps built against a different libc?). Or it might be that some required configuration file isn't there or contains garbage. Can you get a core dump to see where exactly it crashes? Perhaps run an `strace ip addr show dev eth0 > /tmp/OUT` and look at which files it opens? Does `ip addr show` also crash? What does `ip link list` say?

Comment: I have not built `strace` as part of the embedded setup - I will do so ASAP. `ip addr show` also crashes, but `ip link list` displays output without crashing. I will update the question with the output as its too large to write here.

Comment: That means that the links (i.e., basic hardware) is handled correctly (unless it spouts nonsense, that is). The problem is one stage up...

Comment: @vonbrand So basically its an incorrectly configured network?

Comment: Could be, or something else is broken. Do you have any way of checking if a package is damaged? What distribution (packaging system) is this?

Comment: It is not really a distribution as such, it is buildroot. It creates kernel, cross compilers and rootfs for an embedded device. All the `ip` , `ippaddr` etc is done via `busybox` which is also built with buildroot.

Comment: Maybe the busybox implementation of `ip` is borked? Compile elsewhere (in a less confining environment) and check if it works right. Latest busybox? Any reports against this?

Comment: @vonbrand : buildroot is a souped up crosstool that creates the toolchain and the entire base target system, I believe. So (@mathematician) you could end up with a broken libc, but it seems unlikely if tested and everything else works. Note that the kernel is static (no links), so that will not affect it. You need to clarify *exactly* what "I get the report of a segfault in [libc]" means.  Also, installing `gdb` (or taking a core dump and using a cross-gdb?) will help.  If you don't have much experience with a C compiler and debugger, this is going to be a steep uphill climb...

Comment: @goldilocks Im a developer, but the desktop variety so debugging embedded stuff is pretty new. I am not getting a core dump as I built everything without debug info for compactness of the system. I think as a first resort I will roll back to an earlier busybox version and if that doesn't work go at it the hard way. I will upload the full segfault message when I return to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve the segmentation fault issue which I will document here in case anyone has similar problems in the future. I noticed that when I called the following

```
 ip -f inet addr show dev eth0
```

instead of

```
 ip inet addr show dev eth0
```

then the segfault would not happen, but it would still happen with

```
 ip -f inet6 addr show dev eth0
```

This lead me to the conclusion that I must have an incompatibility with IPv6 support somewhere in my toolchain or busybox. I rebuild my entire target, toolchain, kernel and uClibc from scratch once again with the buildroot config files, this time ensuring that my crosstools were created with IPV6 support. With that option set the reported segfault no longer occurs.